# How can I migrate a Drupal 9 database to my own MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, drupal, migration

When I use a tool such as PHPMyAdmin on my own server, that is currently using Drupal, the data is of course encrypted. I want to migrate away from Drupal and create my own custom site and be able to access my original Drupal data such as Users, Images, Nodes. Thanks for any help.

Tried PHPMyAdmin, but data is still encrypted and not usable for my own custom coded site.

Comment: This is out of scope and a  project as such. You will need to export data and reimport in your new DB structure as per fitting your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Civette -- it would be good idea to export the data and then in your own new website import it.
You can either provide REST API to do the export or maybe use something like default_content to export into flat yaml files.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).